# array list display for patient list

Tags: java

I am a beginner and trying to create a patients array list...  i am trying to print the patient details in a tabular format but i would come only in a straight line instead. could someone please help...   thank you in advance 
I want it to print in

```
System.out. print line( "ID No." + "First Name"+ "Last Name"+"Address"+ " 
              Phone Number"+" DOB"+" Age"+" Sex"+"\t"+ " Mail 
              ID"+"\t"+"Social security number");
```

one after the other but they all display in a straight line

Comment: what is `System.out. print line` ?

Comment: You need to change "System.out. print line" to the System.out.println( ...);